# Did Relationship Status on Facebook Get Automatically Hidden?

Tags: facebook

I was looking at my girlfriend's (non-Timeline) Facebook page, and noticed that where it used to say she's in a relationship with me is now gone.

Was there a recent change to make this information automatically hidden, or is it still done manually?

I should probably just ask her, but I'd rather know if there was a change in that setting first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any of the usual uproar that accompanies a change in Facebook's settings on this front. Facebook is in the process of [forcing people onto the timeline format](http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/30/switch-to-timeline/), so possibly it is associated with that change over.

On the whole, it is probably easiest to ask her.